# Запуск какой-то программы(ярлыка) на чужом пк, находящийся в одной сети

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, 1с, windows-server-2008

Не могу нагулить, придется тут спросить.
Есть моя машина и машина-сервер. На ней находится база 1С 7.7 Мне нужно зайти в терминальном доступе туда и запустить задачу(Виндосовский диспечер задач), которая выполняет обмен.

Хочу избавить себя от захода на сервер. Мы просто делаем ярлык задачи, помещаем в какую то папку. И все, что остается, на моей машине дать команду, на запуск этого ярлыка.

Я могу запускать обмен и на своей машине, как и могу войти в базу, но на моей машине обмен совершается за 20 минут(из-за интернет соединения), а на сервере уходит 3 минуты.

Поэтому я бы хотел удаленно запускать эту задачу на сервере. Как это возможно сделать?
Есть еще причина, по которой я не могу запускать это на своей машина - это слетание указанных путей обмена 1С. Да, можно прописать в реестр. Но моя идея в том, чтобы я мог давать свой софт людям, которые смогут запускать на своих машинах.
А пускать посторонних через терминальный доступ, нельзя конечно.  Хотелось бы услышать пару вариантов. Сервер старый. 2008й вроде. NET 4.0 стоит вроде. Находимся в одной сети. Спасибо

Comment: Не пойму логику. Давать терминальный доступ - это нехорошо, а давать право всякие процессы запускать - это норм?

Comment: В терминальном можно зайти в папки и наворотить что угодно. А запустить дистанционно определенный ярлык, не так плохо. Ах да. На сервере один профиль с пользователем. Если будет заходить несколько людей, будут выкидывать друг друга.

Comment: если вам надо что то периодически запускать, почему нельзя для этого виндовский шедулер использовать? Настроил один раз и пусть себе запускает сам.

Comment: Все очень просто. Обмены идут раз в 2ч. они сами по себе и ходят. Но бывают ситуации, которые участились, когда надо запускать внеочередной обмен. Для этого, надо лезть на сервер, запускать задачу. Добавим к этому иерархию в офисе. один просит сделать обмен и пошла цепочка передачи просьбы до того человека, который имеет доступ.. И чтобы этого не было, нужна кнопка, которая будет этот обмен запускать, удаленно. Но это все лирика и не относится к задачи

Comment: Сделайте в системе юзера, которому ничего нельзя делать, вообще ничего. Потом разрешите ему только запускать задачу. И дайте RDP, на рабочем столе которого один единственный ярлык. Делов на час максимум, никаких дотнетов не надо. Еще если 1С-ка клиент-серверная, а не файловая, то внутри 1С-ки можно кнопку сделать. Кстати, 2008 R2 SP1 можно .NET Framework 4.7.2 или 4.8 поставить, чтобы не мучаться с динозавтром 4.0.

Comment: Так. Пользователей заводить мне не дают. Указание начальства. Увы. 1С и так делает все автоматом, если запускать под определенным юзером. Даже кнопки не надо. Есть программа Litemanager. У нее есть функция "Запуск программ". На удаленной машине запускает программы. Вот мне видимо нужен ее аналог. Я все же нашел такое. Это PsExec. Но я катастрофически сомневаюсь в его безопасности. В марке 21го там устранили уязвимость серьезную. Вещь явно ненадежная. Есть еще WMI. она вроде как даже предустановлена везде. Но не понял, можно ли ее использовать как мне надо.

Comment: Просто вкину ссылку, сам не пробовал https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Все без исключения способы удалённого доступа требуют аутентификации в удалённой системе, и обычно им нужны либо права администратора, либо отдельный пользователь специально для этих целей. Каким образом удалённый вход с правами администратора может быть "безопаснее" заведения отдельного пользователя - спрашивайте начальство.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответ. Будем смотреть)

Answer (score 1):

Рассматрите вариант, написать простой WebApi с одним контроллером и методом в нем.

В этом методе будет выполняться запуск нужно приложения.
Путь для запуска можно в конфиге указывать.

Это WebApi надо будет развернуть на сервере (например, с помощью IIS) и когда нужно, вызывать этот метод.

Тут ещё не помешает конечно аутентификация, чтобы как-то ограничить доступ к этому методу.

Answer (score -1):

Могу предложить следующий вариант: пишем программу, запускаем на сервере, которая раз в 2-минуты смотрит в папку, - при наличии там файла 1.txt удаляет его и запускает обмен (.bat) Папку разшариваем, кидаем в нее файл 1.txt когда нужно запустить обмен.

Comment: Ну...Как костыль, почему бы и нет. Возьму на крайний вариант. ОС старая, посмотрим.